# C/C++ file reading error

Tags: c++

I'm getting an error message on this and I'm assuming the problem is with the c/c++ string on the filename. start is a C++ string variable that I've created and I can't use that as it is, in the brackets after inp.open. start.c_str() is what I've been told to do in a lecture, however this doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

```
   else if (start != "") {
        ifstream inp;
        inp.open(start.c_str());
        if (inp.fail()) { error("Could not open file"); }
        string row;
        while (getline(inp, row)) {
            filereadout.push_back(row);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The one from the inp.fail() "Could not open file". There is a packaged version of the exercise that has the files in it, which works fine. So I know it isn't the file..

Comment: start depends on user input, it's a string variable that holds the user input

Comment: just add a print of the file name before `open` to see the name being passed to `open` and check whether the file exists and whether you have read access to it.

Comment: So, probably you need to check first if (inp.is_open()). And be careful with slashes in file name.

Comment: The code have posted is correct. Your problem has nothing to do with strings. There can be a many reasons why you can't open a file. Most likely reason is that you aren't looking for the file where you think you are.

Comment: inp.is_open is returning false.

Comment: No surprise there then, print out the value of `start`, `std::cout << start << '\n'`, and tell us what you see.

Comment: I dumped the files from their files folder into the main directory and that worked. Thanks!

Comment: hint: when an stream appears to fail to open, (1) check the filename, and unless it is fully qualified (2) getcwd() to see where the program is actually running from. You'd be amazed how often people are surprised to find out their current working dir from an IDE launch isn't where they thought it was.

Comment: @WhosCraig indeed, in XCode on Mac it happens... :) Can you please put your comment into an answer?